# Push notification not reaching when app in foreground

Tags: codenameone

I'm having trouble getting Push Notifications when the app is in foreground in an Android device. As soon as I put the app in the background all goes well.

This is the java code I use to send de notifications:

```
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL_SERVER);
    List<NameValuePair> arguments = new ArrayList<>();   
    arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", TOKEN));        
    arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device", codigoApp));      
    arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "1"));        
    arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", ip));                    
    arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("auth", GOOGLE_AUTH));        
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arguments));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);   
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NotificaReview.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

And this is the code in the app:

```
    public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    if (Push.getPushKey() != null)
        devicePush = Push.getPushKey(); 
    else
        Display.getInstance().registerPush(); 
    Form inicioGUI = new InicioGUI(devicePush);
    inicioGUI.show();
}

public void stop() {
    current = getCurrentForm();
    if(current instanceof Dialog) {
        ((Dialog)current).dispose();
        current = getCurrentForm();
    }
}

public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void push(String value) {
  ToastBar.showMessage("Archivo recibido correctamente con IP" + value, FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO);
}

@Override
public void registeredForPush(String deviceId) {
    devicePush = deviceId;
}

@Override
public void pushRegistrationError(String error, int errorCode) {

}
```

The ToastBar only shows when I bring the app to foreground after receiving the push while in background. The Push callback is never called if the app is alive.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using GCM push or FCM push? Which OS is this on? Did you test other devices? Do you see anything printed to the device console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need answers to my comment in the question which might help explain the issue. I'll edit this answer based on the updates to the question.

In the meantime I see several issues in the code. See my highlighted comments/fixes below:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    // don't check the push key, always register the device and 
    // always do it in a callSerially as it might trigger a prompt
    callSerially(() -> registerPush()); 
    Form inicioGUI = new InicioGUI(Push.getPushKey());
    inicioGUI.show();
}

@Override
public void push(String value) {
  ToastBar.showMessage("Archivo recibido correctamente con IP" + value, FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO);
}

@Override
public void registeredForPush(String deviceId) {
    // deviceId is the native push key you need to use the actual 
    // push key value never device ID
    devicePush = Push.getPushKey();
}

@Override
public void pushRegistrationError(String error, int errorCode) {
    // you might have gotten a push error which might have explained the
    // cause of the problem
    Log.p("Push error " + errorCode + ":" + error);
    Log.sendLogAsync();
}
```